# replace getdate with column name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select convert(date,GETDATE()) as [date], 
convert(varchar(8), convert(time, '2013-06-03 00:00:00.000')) as [Time]
```

I want to get date and time seperately and I use above method.

I'm trying to replace getdate() with my table column name:

```
select convert(date,dbo.tbltimetable.AppDate) as [date], 
convert(varchar(8), convert(time, dbo.tbltimetable.AppDate)) as [Time]
```

this doesn't seem to help: I get an error saying'multipart identifier could not be bound'
Where I'm going wrong. Please help.

Comment: Where is `FROM TableName` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `FROM <TableName>`
Try:

```
select convert(date,AppDate) as [date], 
  convert(varchar(8), convert(time,AppDate)) as [Time]
FROM dbo.tbltimetable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
select convert(date,tbltimetable.AppDate) as [date], 
convert(varchar(8), convert(time, tbltimetable.AppDate)) as [Time]
from tbltimetable
```